# Why can't I update googlemaps polyline from a viewmodel MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

Bear with me - new to Kotlin so probably missing something obvious. As commented in the fragment code  'myPolyLine?.points = it' doesn't work but 'myPolyLine?.points = pLines.value' does (problem being that if I navigate away from the fragment I lose the existing polyline).  Snip from Fragment:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mapViewModel: MapViewModel
    private var myPositionMarker: Marker? = null
    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    private var myPolyLine: Polyline? = null
     private var isPolyAdded: Boolean = false
     private lateinit var mo:MarkerOptions
    private  var pLines:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>> = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>>()

    private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
        this.googleMap = googleMap
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0F))
         mo = MarkerOptions()
     }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        pLines.value = ArrayList<LatLng>()
        mapViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MapViewModel::class.java)

        mapViewModel.theLocation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val position = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position))
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0F))
            if (myPositionMarker == null) {
                myPositionMarker = googleMap.addMarker(
                    mo.position(position).title("Me")
                )
            } else {
                myPositionMarker!!.position = position
            }
            pLines.value?.add(position)
        })

        mapViewModel.points.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (this::googleMap.isInitialized) {
                if (!isPolyAdded) {
                    var lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
                        .color(Color.RED)
                        .width(8F)
                    myPolyLine = googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions)
                    isPolyAdded = true
                } else {
                    //Why doesn't this work (doesn't show polyline):
                    myPolyLine?.points = it
                    //But this does:
                    myPolyLine?.points = pLines.value
//Shows expected size in both cases
                    Log.d("Fragment", "myPolyLine has ${myPolyLine?.points?.size} points")
                }
            }
        })


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class MapViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){

     private val repo = LocationRepository(application)
     lateinit var theLocation: LiveData<Location>
    lateinit var points: LiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>>

    init {
        theLocation = repo.theLocation
        points = repo.points
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        Log.d("View Model", " Cleared")
        super.onCleared()
        repo.unregister()
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class LocationRepository(context: Context) {
    var theLocation: MutableLiveData<Location> = MutableLiveData()
    private var internalPoints: ArrayList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
    var points: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>> = MutableLiveData()

    val context: Context = context
    private val lr0: BroadcastReceiver

    init {
        points.value = ArrayList<LatLng>()
       // points = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>>()
        lr0 = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                val currentlocation = intent?.getParcelableExtra<Location>("Location")

                theLocation.setValue(currentlocation)
                if (currentlocation != null) {
                    internalPoints.add(LatLng(currentlocation.longitude, currentlocation.latitude))
                    points.value = internalPoints
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("Repo"," Registering receiver")
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter("locationChange")
        context.registerReceiver(lr0, intentFilter)
    }

    fun unregister() {
        Log.d("Repo"," Unregistering receiver")
        context.unregisterReceiver(lr0)
    }


}
```

Comment: 1. Not use a livedat in the UI, is not necessary, you create pLines but only is an Array, you don´t need to observe it, so use only List<LatLng>. 2. pLines.value works because has data, you added using the next pLines.value?.add(position) onCreateView.  3. Don´t use a lateinit livedata in the VM to init in the constructor, use the Transformations.map or switchmap to consume the repo livedata from viewmodel livedata.  4. Verify your it data, what value has? Maybe is empty

Comment: @ManuelMato Hi, Thanks for the reply.  All of the pLines stuff was just an attempt to get it working.  On your point 4: ' it' has the correct number of points so I guess my question really boils down to asking why 'myPolyLine?.points = it' does not work (note that after this line then 'myPolyLine?.points?.size' also shows the expected value)

Comment: Duh! Discovered that I was reversing Lat and Long in the room database.  Polyline was being drawn but somewhere out in the Pacific Ocean......